# How to get ejabberd server response messages for Rest API calls

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to make use of ejabberd REST API calls by following this -
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/. I would like to do things like publishing to pubsub nodes or sending messages to clients by directly calling the APIs from a program or script.

I have configured the ejabberd server and tested ok with curl and Postman. Now, I would like to know if one can get detailed status messages of the API calls from the server back to the caller (program or script). Currently, the server only returns status codes of 0 for success and 1 otherwise for many of the calls.

In some cases, the API call may succeed but error may occur (for example, error in stanza). In the ejabberd debug logs, we can see the server replies back to the sender with iq stanzas with type=result or error. However, if the sender is not an XMPP client such as Postman or a Python script, the sender will have no way to receive it. Sure, we can use another XMPP client's JID in the "from" field but then we need to maintain an XMPP client and let it run all the time which we don't want.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What are result/error-stanzas do you get? Since for what I know the only iq you should get without doing anything is a ping. For the other commands you send, there are the return code as written in the API-guide.

Comment: As an example, I sent this message from Postman to a non-existent user using api/send_stanza. 
`
{
 "from": "admin_user@1.2.3.4/server1",
 "to": "userXXX@1.2.3.4/ANDROID",
 "stanza": "<message type='chat'><body>Hi</body></message>"
}
`
Postman received reply code of 0 (success). However, ejabberd's debug logs show this error.
`
#message{id = <<>>,type = error
...
sub_els = [#stanza_error{type = cancel,code = 503,by = undefined,
                                  reason = 'service-unavailable',text = [],
                                  sub_els = []}],`

Comment: However, if I send to an existing account, the debug message shows success #message{id = <<>>,type = chat. We would like to receive the status messages at the API caller, if possible.@TubifFux

Comment: The success code is about the act of sending the stanza itself. Technical, the send can be performed, even if the target user does not exist. If you want the sanity check of the full XMPP stack, for now, you would need to send the message using XMPP directly, or write your own custom module API to perform the check you would like to do before injecting the stanza in ejabberd router.